# Problems about create dynamic columns with jgGrid

Tags: spring-mvc, jqgrid, thymeleaf

I made a demo to create dynamic columns with `jqGrid` table, but faced with some problems. This is the jqGrid code snippet:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "get",
        url: "reports/providerList",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            var colNames = result.rows.colNames;
            var colModels = result.rows.colModels;
            $(grid_selector).jqGrid('GridUnload');

            jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
                url: 'reports/getData',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'get',
                colNames: colNames,
                colModel: colModels,
                viewrecords : true,
                rownumbers:true,
                rowNum:15,
                rowList:[15,30],
                pager : pager_selector,
                altRows: true,
                loadComplete : function() {
                    var table = this;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        updatePagerIcons(table);
                        enableTooltips(table);
                    }, 0);
                },
            });
        },
        error: function(x, e)
        {
            alert(x.readyState + " "+ x.status +" "+ e.msg);
        }
    });
```

my backend controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/providerList")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> providerList(@RequestParam(value = "rows", required = false) Integer pageSize, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer pageNumber){
        JQGridModel jqGridModel = new JQGridModel();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashedMap();
        map.put("total", 4);
        map.put("rows", jqGridModel);
        map.put("records", 6);
        return map;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getData")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getData(){
        List<ColData> colDatas = new ArrayList<>();
        ColData colData1 = new ColData(2, "hello", new Date().toString(), "true", "admin");
        ColData colData2 = new ColData(5, "say", new Date().toString(), "false", "pechen");
        colDatas.add(colData1);
        colDatas.add(colData2);
        colDatas.add(colData2);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashedMap();
        map.put("total", 4);
        map.put("rows", colDatas);
        map.put("records", 6);
        return map;
    }
```

The data format at backend:

```
public class JQGridModel {
    private List<String> colNames;
    private List<ColModel> colModels;

    public JQGridModel() {
        colNames = new ArrayList<>();
        colNames.add("id");
        colNames.add("name");
        colNames.add("createTime");
        colNames.add("status");
        colNames.add("updateBy");

        colModels = new ArrayList<>();
        ColModel colModel1 = new ColModel("id", "id", 60f, false, false);
        ColModel colModel2 = new ColModel("name", "index", 60f, false, false);
        colModels.add(colModel1);
        colModels.add(colModel2);
        colModels.add(colModel2);
        colModels.add(colModel2);
        colModels.add(colModel2);
    }
}
```

But I only to get this outcomes, no data shown in some columns:
[image]

I noticed the `/reports/providerList` and `/reports/getData` was hit in debug mode. What's going wrong, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the error seems to me the last lines of your `JQGridModel` constructor. You use `colModels.add(colModel2)` multiple times. It's wrong. The `colNames` contains **labels**: the texts displayed in the column headers. One allow to use duplicates or empty strings in `colNames`. On the other side the `colModel` have to contains **unique** `name` values, which can't be empty, can't contains spaces.

You have to change the code of `JQGridModel` constructor `colModels` to fill it with the names, which you use currently to fill `colNames`.

Comment: thanks, it's indeed the cause of the error, and the `name` should be the same with `field` in colData.